# Multiple cache creations in Gemfire

Tags: java, spring-data, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I'm trying to create a local-cache and a client-cache inside one JVM, however i get the error stated below which i think is occuring due to cache being singleton and you can only create one per JVM.

Does anybody know a good work around?

Error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'ccf': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The singleton cache was created by CacheFactory not ClientCacheFactory.
```

Cache.xml:

```
<gfe:cache id="localCache"/> 

<gfe:client-cache id="ccf" pool-name="gfPool" properties-ref="clientCacheProperties" />

<gfe:pool id="gfPool" subscription-enabled="true" load-conditioning-interval="6000" socket-buffer-size="65535" thread-local-connections="true" read-timeout="6000"
    idle-timeout="6000" retry-attempts="-1" ping-interval="5000" max-connections="-1">
    <gfe:locator host="127.0.0.1" port="10083" />
</gfe:pool>

<gfe:local-region id="localRegion"  cache-ref="localCache"/> 

<gfe:client-region id="region" cache-ref="ccf" pool-name="gfPool" name="regionName" shortcut="CACHING_PROXY"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't define more than one cache in the same JVM. A cache is a singleton. See the  [API docs](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vfabric-gemfire/700-api/index.html).